# Add number / text inside d3 path

Tags: javascript, d3.js, path, label, line

How would I add a text or numeric label inside an arc, using d3?

I have the paths drawn the way I want but am struggling to get the text inside it?

I would like to add the value of "count" for each path at the start of the path

I have added what I have so far below as well as creating a pen (see link below)

[CODEPEN LINK](http://codepen.io/alandunning/pen/KpKjBW)

```
var width = 300, height = 300;
var twoPi = 2 * Math.PI; // Full circle
var formatPercent = d3.format(".0%");

var data = [
  { "count" : 1000 },
  { "count" : 800 },
  { "count" : 800 },
  { "count" : 700 }
];

var max = d3.max(data, function(d) { 
  return +d.count;
});

var percent = d3.max(data, function(d) { 
  return +d.count / 10;
});

var radius = .25;
var gap = 22;
var maxCount = max + percent;

var cx = width / 2.5;
var cy = height / 2.5;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
        .attr("width", width)
    .attr("height", height)
    .append("g")
    .attr("transform", "translate(" + width / 10 + "," + height / 10 + ")");

    svg.selectAll("path")
        .data(data).enter()
      .append("path")
        .each(drawArc);

function drawArc(d, i) {
  var ratio = d.count / maxCount;
  var arc = d3.svg.arc()
        .startAngle(0)
        .endAngle(twoPi * ratio)
        .innerRadius(0 + gap * radius)
        .outerRadius(20 + gap * radius);

  d3.select(this)
        .attr("transform", "translate(" + cx + "," + cy + ")")
        .attr("d", arc);
        radius++;
}
```

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This was already [answered](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903548/draw-text-in-d3-arc-javascript).

You need to assign an id to your paths, and then set the `xlink:href` attribute in your text nodes pointing to the corresponding path id.

```
var text = svg.append("text")
    .attr("x", 6)
    .attr("dy", 15);

text.append("textPath")
    .attr("xlink:href","#yourPathId")
    .text("My counter text");
```

[This is the codepen](http://codepen.io/anon/pen/NqWQNg) with some changes to reflect that.

Comment: Thanks, this worked perfect. I xannot up-vote the answer as I have a rep below 15. I will up-vote it when I get above 15.