# d3Js - how to arrange my values as around the 360d and automate data in a circle?

Tags: d3.js

I have a data like this:

```
var requiredDegrees = [0,30,60,90,120,150,180,210,240,270,300,330,360];
```

I would like to arrange this data in a cirlce around. how to calculate and palace the degrees across my circle.

And I would like to create the same as like this http://windhistory.com/station.html?KCFE by `3d.js` any one suggest me the correct way here please?

Comment: Same issue in that question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/13903548/draw-text-in-d3-arc-javascript

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Simplest example I can code up:

```
var requiredDegrees = [0, 30, 60, 90, 120, 150, 180, 210, 240, 270, 300, 330, 360];

var diameter = 300;

var svg = d3.select("body").append("svg")
  .attr("width", diameter + 50)
  .attr("height", diameter + 50)
  .append("g")
  .attr("transform", "translate(25,25)");

svg.append("circle")
  .attr("transform", "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + diameter / 2 + ")")
  .attr("r", diameter / 2)

 svg.selectAll('text')
  .data(requiredDegrees)
  .enter()
  .append('text')
  .text(function(d) {
    return d;
  })
  .attr('transform', function(d) {
    return "translate(" + diameter / 2 + "," + 0 + ") rotate(" + d + ",0," + diameter / 2 + ")";
  });
```

Demonstration [here](http://plnkr.co/edit/nfiYEUfBkbewMGk0G1Bo?p=preview).